# How to get "Element" -type value from "Element.parentNode" instead of "Node & ParentNode"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The recipe of event delegating from http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/:

```
document.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
    // loop parent nodes from the target to the delegation node
    for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
        if (target.matches(elementSelector)) {
            handler.call(target, e);
            break;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

I am trying rewrite it to TypeScript type-safely (for click event for now):

```js
export default function delegateClickEventHandling(
    {
      clickTargetSelector,
      container = document
    }: {
      clickTargetSelector: string;
      container: HTMLElement | Document;
    },
    handler: (event: MouseEvent) => void
): void {

  container.addEventListener("click", (event: Event): void => {

    if (!(event instanceof MouseEvent)) {
      return;
    }

    for (
        let targetParentNode: Element | null = event.target as Element;
        isNotNull(targetParentNode) && targetParentNode !== event.currentTarget;
        targetParentNode = targetParentNode.parentNode
    ) {

      if (targetParentNode.matches(clickTargetSelector)) {
        handler(event);
      }
    }
  }, false);
}
```

TypeScript compiler tells me:

```
TS2322: Type '(Node & ParentNode) | null' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.
Type 'Node & ParentNode' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.
Type 'Node & ParentNode' is missing the following properties from type 'Element':
 assignedSlot, attributes, classList, className, and 64 more.
```

The `.matches()` is the method of the `Element` - I can't to call it from `Node & ParentNode`).
What have I do?

If `targetParentNode = targetParentNode.parentNode as Element` is completely all right please explain why.

P. S. Please note that `any`, `object` and type annotation omitting are not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to cast `targetParentNode.parentNode` to `Element`.

So `for loop` might be look like this:

```
for (
    let targetParentNode: Element = event.target as Element;
    targetParentNode !== event.currentTarget;
    targetParentNode = targetParentNode.parentNode as Element
) {

  if (targetParentNode.matches(clickTargetSelector)) {
    handler(event);
  }
}
```

[PlaygrounLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYBtUHMCGVUDC6MEA1gKIBuqYUAEjmMsWFgBQCwAUIr4gN7c%20fCMTIAVHACcsqKAGUMqaHCkAaIcMQQEUHDDCopiALwo4EEAFsaUTbwC%20ALgH2RY0pJlzFmFVJcAZygpAywAbjdeHVp9QwDEOnEAWQAZckwbWkQAH0QAEQtrW0iePgcNMt4AC0ZmIxc2VGpaF2S4EEDUKlsASlMAPkRKOBhkbl6XEbHXLk0YvQMjADocZGQe2lSYYJojNgAiURJSA7VEJpaoF02oSeHR5EHZtxhgC4BCS9tEA2DGCCoODvdqdbpXXr9QRVPhSOQgKRgUrCBzcNzAVQXKJ8TBQRB6bxQAAK0lsADk4GgbpkfnkwCB0OhTIhmrZlgTZHicIFEBlUFkoMitLwdhSoGSGeg2By5CS4bQKWh%20gAyZX46ScuXkymoRAfExmVm0ZaWKTyqBeTlC4Uy4mkhU65m2rUOtDLAAO9vFju5vJptDcULRMJF72lGtlXsVqGWVjwEGqqECbGOEgjCiU-khs2FNTqmCk31ovWt5TcqLKFUQwBw6C6Je4Fe4oEgsAQv0CYoljPDhJd3qpfv5thy9MZQZhb17mqjOt62MQcKgCKQIRAqFLS5X1drXVKFaAA)

Comment: Thank you for the solution! But is it safe to consider `Node & ParentNode` as `Element`?

Comment: Yes, And also you can use `parentElement ` instead of  `parentNode` . look like this: `targetParentNode = targetParentNode.parentElement as Element `

Comment: O'K! I upvoted and accepted you answer. Appreciate it!